# Iterative Collatz with memoization

Tags: python, optimization, algorithm, recursion, memoization

I'm trying to write efficient code for calculating the chain-length of each number.

For example, `13 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1`.
It took 13 iterations to get 13 down to 1, so `collatz(13)` = `10`.

Here is my implementation:

```
def collatz(n, d={1:1}):
    if not n in d:
        d[n] = collatz(n * 3 + 1 if n & 1 else n/2) + 1
    return d[n]
```

It's quite efficient, but I'd like to know whether the same efficiency (or better) can be achieved by an iterative one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Python call stack to remember your state is very convenient and often results in shorter code, but it has a disadvantage:

```
>>> collatz(5**38)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "cr24195.py", line 3, in collatz
    d[n] = collatz(n * 3 + 1 if n & 1 else n/2) + 1
  [... many lines omitted ...]
  File "cr24195.py", line 3, in collatz
    d[n] = collatz(n * 3 + 1 if n & 1 else n/2) + 1
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

You need to remember all the numbers you've visited along the way to your cache hit *somehow*. In your recursive implementation you remember them on the call stack. In an iterative implementation one would have to remember this stack of numbers in a list, perhaps like this:

```py
def collatz2(n, d = {1: 1}):
    """Return one more than the number of steps that it takes to reach 1
    starting from `n` by following the Collatz procedure.

    """
    stack = []
    while n not in d:
        stack.append(n)
        n = n * 3 + 1 if n & 1 else n // 2
    c = d[n]
    while stack:
        c += 1
        d[stack.pop()] = c
    return c
```

This is a bit verbose, and it's slower than your recursive version:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:map(collatz, xrange(1, 10**6)), number=1)
2.7360708713531494
>>> timeit(lambda:map(collatz2, xrange(1, 10**6)), number=1)
3.7696099281311035
```

But it's more robust:

```
>>> collatz2(5**38)
1002
```